# Openfire MUC Through HTTP Requests

Tags: plugins, openfire, http-request

I've been searching high and low for a plugin that handles MUC administration through HTTP requests for Openfire. I've looked in the [plugins](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins.jsp) and even in the [community](http://community.igniterealtime.org/community/plugins/commplugins?view=documents) pages but I've had no luck so far.

Is there a plugin for this? Where can I find it?

If there are none, what are my alternatives aside from creating my own? Kinda like how ejabberd has mod_rest or even ejabberdctl.

If anyone can point me to the right direction, that would be really great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a service for http requests and linking it to Openfire's MySQL back end. Easier and gives me more control.

Answer (score 0):

Openfire have cache mechanism， Directly operate Mysql table have some issue, User information will delay before openfire cash flush.

I do it by xmpphp, and a new method to add muc room and room member by xmpp protocol, but i need user's password every operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you check again the Plugin site from Openfire you will find out that there is a Plugin for that named "MUC Service". That do exactly what you need.

Here is the documentation: http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/mucservice/readme.html